# Playing Apple Keynote v8.2 presentation programmatically in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, quartz-graphics, avkit, keynote

I've got **Apple Keynote v8.2** presentation project having **`.key`** extension. This presentation contains 5 videos with 4 identical transitions between them. The name of transition is **`Clothesline`**.

***I have two questions***:

1. Is it possible to use and play **`.key`** file format programmatically using Swift?
2. If the first question is true, is it possible to start **`Clothesline`** transition using keyboard, not a mouse click?

[image]

`macOS 10.14 Mojave`, `Apple Keynote v8.2`, `Xcode v10`, `Swift v4.2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it's turned out that at the moment there's no API for working with Apple Keynote presentations and `.key` file format. There's only `ImageKit` module that provides user interface support for browsing, editing, and saving images as well as showing slideshows. `ImageKit` is a part of [Quartz](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz) framework.